# change next_run_time at a job

Tags: sql, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I have some jobs in sql and I need to change the next run date and time from code. I have the following stored procedure the updates the job, but the job does not starts at the specified time:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pu_usp_update_ssis_package]
    @job_id varchar(50) ,
    @next_run_date int,
    @next_run_time int
AS
begin
    update 
        msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules 
    set 
        next_run_date = @next_run_date,
        next_run_time = @next_run_time
    where 
        job_id = @job_id
end
```

The data is updated in the table `msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules` for my job, but I don't know why the job does not starts

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updates stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pu_usp_update_ssis_package]
    @job_id varchar(50) ,
    @next_run_date int,
    @next_run_time int
AS
begin
declare @schedule_id int
set @schedule_id = (select 
                        msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.schedule_id 
                    from 
                        msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules 
                    where 
                        job_id = @job_id)

    exec msdb..sp_update_schedule @schedule_id = @schedule_id,
                            @active_start_date  = @next_run_date, 
                            @active_start_time = @next_run_time

end
```